# Can't get sencha touch 2 to sort my data after update in list

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm currently trying to display a list in sencha with data from a store. When I fire an ajax request and update this store the changes are reflected in the list (the right numbers are changed), but it doesn't re-sort the list. The list is sorted at the first load, but then never again. Does anybody know how to re-sort the list after an update? I've tried with adding a listener to refresh and resorting my store from there, but that doesn't help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using the pull to refresh plugin? I am and had to override what the refresh method did (as per the doc's):

```
    plugins: [
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
            pullRefreshText: 'Refresh',
            refreshFn: function() {
                this.getList().setMasked(true);
                this.getList().getStore().load();
            }
        }
    ]
```

The extra mask call is there to mask over the list because the pull to refresh doesn't wait for the data to be returned before hiding itself (giving the false impression that the list has been updated already).